# firebase user getting null on restart of application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputLayout e1;
    private TextInputLayout e2;
    private TextInputEditText e21;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private String user_id;
    private String value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
        e1=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email);
        e2=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
        e21=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.password_ed);
        e21.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > e2.getCounterMaxLength())
                    e2.setError("Max character length is " + e2.getCounterMaxLength());
                else
                    e2.setError(null);
            }
        });
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Signing In...");
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);

    }

    public void login(View view){
        email = e1.getEditText().getText().toString();
        password = e2.getEditText().getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (password.length() < 8) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password Must Be Of Length 8", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            login_user(email, password);
            progress.show();
        }

    }
    private void login_user(final String email, String password) {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(Authentication.this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user.isEmailVerified()){
                    user_id = user.getUid();
                    Toast.makeText(Authentication.this,"Login Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progress.dismiss();
                    DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user_id).child("Information");
                    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    showCustomDialog_error();
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnFailureListener(Authentication.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Authentication.this,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showCustomDialog_error() {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.error_custom, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        Button bt= (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Authentication.this,"Email Not Verified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e1.getEditText().setText(null);
                e2.getEditText().setText(null);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        });
        Button bt2= (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsent);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                user.sendEmailVerification();
                showCustomDialog_tick();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showCustomDialog_tick() {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tick_custom, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        TextView tv=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.customtv);
        tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.verification_email_sent_successfully));
        TextView tv2=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.customtv1);
        tv2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.verify_email_and_then_login_again));
        Button bt = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                e1.getEditText().setText(null);
                e2.getEditText().setText(null);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        });
        Button bt1 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsent);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                user.sendEmailVerification();
                showCustomDialog_tick();
            }
        });
    }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (user != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Info.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
 }
```

my firebase user is getting null after app restart
i.e. onStart method is not working
explain me why my user is getting null after the successfull login and then restarting the application.
i have also tried onAuthStatechangeLitsner but its not working..
it is still get my user null.
i have tried many of the approaches debug the code and search in a logcat too but same issue

Comment: You should definitely use an auth state listener. Read: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0

Answer (score 1):

After signing in, the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` may not be set yet. For this reason, you need to get the user from the `AuthResult` parameter that is passed to your completion handler:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(Authentication.this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
        user= authResult.getUser();
        if(user.isEmailVerified()){
           ...
```